# Капитализация процентов в масиве

Tags: java, массивы, ооп

Нужно написать программу, которая будет спрашивать пользователя сколько ему лет, во сколько он хочет выйти на пенсию, сколько он может откладывать денег в год и банковскую ставку на депозит. После этого программа должна создать массив размером столько сколько лет осталось до пенсии, и в каждый элемент в массиве начиная с 0-го заполнить отложенными деньгами + ставка в денежном эквиваленте, проценты должны также капитализироваться, то есть каждый следующий год считается по принципу вклад + проценты (ставка) + и что в год отложил и это все снова под проценты до следующего года. В результате должен быть выведен массив в столбик слева возраст пользователя по праву сумма накоплений.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //x*(1+a)
    System.out.print("How are you?");
    int age = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How much deposit");
    int vklad = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Vik pensiynuy");
    int vikpens = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Stavka");
    int stavka = sc.nextInt();
    int zaoshad =vikpens-age;
    System.out.println("Ви будете откладивать" + " " + zaoshad + " " + "год" +  " " + "По"+ " "
            + vklad + " " + " в год"+ " " + "с процентной ставкой "+ " "
            + stavka);

        int [] mass= new int[zaoshad];
    for (int i = 0; i < zaoshad+1; i++) {

        mass[i]= (vklad*stavka)/100 ;
        System.out.println(mass[i]);
    }
```

Почему то не получается просумировать, уже всю голову сломал. Не знаю как сделать чтоб пред. год просумировать со след и т.д. Подскажите, желательно с коментами) Спасибо всем наперед.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите у вас идет цикл до `zaoshad+1`, а массив создаете размером `zaoshad`. Т.е. происходит выход за размер массива, поэтому у вас и ругается.
А считать капитализацию нужно таким образом:

```
for (int i=0; i < zaoshad; i++) {
    if (i>0)
        mass[i] = vklad + mass[i-1] + mass[i-1]*stavka/100;
    else
        mass[i] = vklad;
    System.out.println("Возраст = " + (age + i) + " накопление = " + mass[i]);
}
```

Comment: Что то не так, не сумирует каждый год новый вклад +100 к примеру каждый год: How old are you?55
How much deposit100
Vik pensiynuy60
Stavka20
Ви будете откладивать 5 год По 100  в год с процентной ставкой  20
Возраст = 55 накопление = 0
Возраст = 56 накопление = 100
Возраст = 57 накопление = 120
Возраст = 58 накопление = 124
Возраст = 59 накопление = 124

Comment: Забыл к каждому году прибавлять вклад с прошлого года. Поправил